# Need with crontab and gui python popup

Tags: python, cron

I have following python script, and want to run it with cron so that every minute cron will popup a message.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gtk.gdk
import pynotify
import random

m=[]
m.append("test1")
m.append("test2")
m.append("test3")

n = pynotify.Notification(random.choice(m))
n.set_hint('x', gtk.gdk.screen_width()/2.)
n.set_hint('y', gtk.gdk.screen_height()/2.)
n.show()
```

This is my cron script:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && /home/user/scripts/notifications.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Unfortunately nothing happens. Can you help please?

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else is wondering. I had to export DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY

I'm running this script in cron:

```
export XAUTHORITY=/home/user/.Xauthority
export DISPLAY=:0
python ~/notifications.py
```

Comment: I had similar problems with a script that just need info from GNOME via the X session vars. Truly truly annoying stuff.

Comment: You can also do these from within the python script: os.environ["DISPLAY"] = ':0'

Answer (score 1):

From [this thread at Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-105250.html), you're possibly running into `xauth` problems. X tends to be paranoid about giving display/input access to outside processes, even from the same user.

In an X terminal window, type: `xhost local:$USER` and see if your cron job works. If so, add that command to your `~/.bashrc` file and the fix should persist.